# Spell Check: How do you specify a different country code in the queryLanguage param?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

In Azure Cognitive Search, I am trying to use the spell checker feature as part of API version "2020-06-30-Preview". For example:

```
"search": "colr",
"speller": "lexicon",
"queryLanguage": "en-us"
```

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/preview-api/search-documents#queryLanguage), I should be able to use any of the queryLanguage parameters listed here:

```
en, en-US (default), en-GB, en-IN, en-CA, en-AU
```

However, it seems like I can only use "en" or "en-US" so how can I specify "en-CA"? When I try it, I get the following error:

```
"message": "Invalid language value: 'en-CA'. Supported languages for speller are: en-US, de-DE, fr-FR, es-ES, nl-NL\r\nParameter name: queryLanguage"
```

Also, is there a way to get the properly spelled terms before doing the search so we can display a "Did you mean..." message?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The speller feature only supports a subset of languages supported by the `queryLanguage` parameter as stated in the documentation.

> At this time, language support varies by feature. Only English, Spanish, French, and German are supported for the full set of features, but notice that spell check implements fewer variants. 
>  
>  If you specify a language code that is not supported by a given feature, such as EN-GB with speller, the service will return HTTP 400.

The list of languages supported by speller can be found here -
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/speller-how-to-add

Comment: Thanks. Where did you copy that text from? I don't see it in the article. And what's the difference between "en" and "en-US" in the queryLanguage param?